# JAVA multiple constructors and IF's vs Inheritence

Tags: java, coding-style

Maybe someone know which way, of writing code is better(less memory,fastest for CPU or GPU).

1st way:
Writing one class for all instances with several constructors and "IF's" checking which parameters exist? Example:

```
class SomeClass
{
  Parameter a;
  Parameter b;
  Parameter c;

   SomeClass(Parameter a)
  {
   this.a=a;
  }

 SomeClass(Parameter a,Parameter b)
  {
   this(a);
   this.b=b;
  }

   SomeClass(Parameter a,Parameter b,Parameter c)
  {
   this(a,b);
   this.c=c;
  }

public void method()
{
if(a!=null && b!=null && c!=null)
DO IN ONE WAY
if(a!=null && b!=null && c==null)
DO IN ANOTHER WAY
if(a!=null && b!=null && c==null)
DO IN ANOTHER WAY
if(a!=null && b==null && c==null)
DO IN ANOTHER WAY
...
    }
}
```

2nd way:
Extend parent class each time inherid parent class when you need to use more parameters. Example:

```
   class SomeClass
    {
      protected Parameter a;

       SomeClass(Parameter a)
      {
       this.a=a;
      }
      public void method()
      {USE a parameter}
    }

    class SomeClass2 extends SomeClass
    {
      protected Parameter b;

       SomeClass2(Parameter a,Parameter b)
      {
       super(a);
       this.b=b;
      }
      public void method()
      {USE a and b parameter}
     }
```

Tell me please which way is better and why?

Comment: This kind of question is better asks at [http://codereview.stackexchange.com/](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I am not sure whether this is better discussed at http://codereview.stackexchange.com or not.

Comment: You shouldn't make the decision based on performance, since the differences will probably be very small. You should make the decision based on which code is more readable, extendible, and makes more sense in general.

Comment: Performance shouldn't be an issue in this question. As far as best practices, the 2nd way is far more flexible, maintainable, structured, readable etc.

Comment: as I understand well, the 2nd way is better to use, if there is such possibility ?

Comment: I agree with the comments, however, while inheritance is more structured, it is not necesarrily more flexible and mantainable. If you want to get rid of the class with Parameter A, you will have to do a lot of refactoring. If you need one with only Parameter C, it is not achievable with inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would even propose a third way:

```
interface SomeClass
{
  public void method();
}

class SomeClassWithOneParameter implements SomeClass
{
  private Parameter a;

   SomeClassWithOneParameter(Parameter a)
  {
   this.a=a;
  }
  public void method()
  {USE a parameter}
 }

class SomeClassWithTwoParameters implements SomeClass
{
  private Parameter a;
  private Parameter b;

   SomeClassWithOneParameter(Parameter a,Parameter b)
  {
   this.a=a;
   this.b=b;
  }
  public void method()
  {USE a and b parameter}
 }
```

Now you can use a pattern like a factory to abstract your code from the specific implementations:

```
class SomeClassFactory
{
    public SomeClass createSomeClassWithOneParam(Parameter a) 
    {
        return new SomeClassWithOneParameter(a);
    }

    public SomeClass createSomeClassWithTwoParams(Parameter a, Parameter b) 
    {
        return new SomeClassWithTwoParameters(a, b);
    }

}
```

Problem with inheritance is that it's the hardest-possible coupling. Imagine that some day, your class with only the a parameter gets obsolete... You would have to do a hell of refactoring to get rid of that class, just because all of your other classes depend on it... If you need a class with only parameter c, why inherit it from the one with parameter a? The best common denominator should not be based on fields (in your case parameters), but on functionality, and that's the `method()`.

The only advantage in the inheritance tree you propose is that you avoid having the parameter definitions repeated in different implementations of your class. This has however no performance difference, you just do a bit less coding, and it is way less flexible than using the interface pattern.

About the first method you propose. It has the problem that you will end up having a big class that is likely to be modified for too many reasons. If you work in a team, it can potentially become a class that everyone has to modify with each requirement, thus affecting mantainability and readability.

A good reading would be the book "Clean Code" from Robert Martin...